# Opening a Word document with a relative path from c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, ms-word

First I'll explain the project structure:

- Solution

  - Templates

    - Sport

      - Sport.doc
- Opendoc.aspx

  - Opendoc.aspx.cs

Now the problem.
In the Opendoc.aspx.cs I'm trying to open Sport.doc but that isn't working when i'm using a relative path. only when I hard code it like c://Sport.doc.

After I click on a button on that page I go to this method:

```
protected void btnCreateWordBulletin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Sport/Sport.doc");
    string Savepath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Sport/SportEvent.doc");
    CreateWordDocument(path, Savepath );
}

protected void CreateWordDocument(object fileName, object saveAs)
{
    //Set Missing Value parameter - used to represent
    //a missing value when calling methods through interop
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    //Setup the Word.App class
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = null;
    // Check to see that file exists
    if (System.IO.File.Exists((string)fileName))
    {... Activating doc etc...}}
```

But the System.IO.File.exists doesn't seem to find the document.

I tried using .//Sport/sport.doc , ../Sport.doc, .//Template/Sport/sport.doc, ..//Template/Sport.doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
HttpApplication.Server.MapPath("/Solution/Templates/Sport/Sport.doc");
```

Thanks!
Also please comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more how I should use it? It tells me Error 1 An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpApplication.Server.get'

Comment: Yes, surely, this will append the path specified in Parameter1 to the current ServerPath (= path of your solution). Also you will need to add the reference `System.Web` to your Using-block. Additionally, since this returns a string-value, you need to assign it to something, e.g. `string a = Server.MapPath("/");`. Should this not work (which it does for me in a CodeBehind-File), use `HttpApplication.Current.Server.MapPath("/")` instead.

Comment: Duh, I meant `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");` of course. Note: this won't work with Asynchronous methods.

Comment: String a= Server.MapPath("/Solution/Templates/Sport/Sport.doc");
String b= Server.MapPath("/Solution/Templates/Sport/SportSave.doc");
CreateWordDocument(a, b);


Solved it.
Thanks for your quick response and great help.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please Upvote (Arrow Up above the huge 0 in my post) and accept the answer (tickmark next to it). Thanks!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do a upvote :), but when i got the 15 rep that i need I will do that :), And tnx again :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would be `../Solution/Templates/Sport/Sport.doc`?

EDIT: Actually, It would just be `/Solution/Templates/Sport/Sport.doc` If the aspx file is in the same folder as the Solution folder.

Bottom line is, you need to refernce the Solution folder.

Comment: That's not fixing it. And while debugging I saw that
 
string path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Sport/Sport.doc");

does the same thing

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific over the file structure. For example, "Opendoc.aspx.cs" is NOT a child of "Opendoc.aspx", it is a sibling.

Comment: I was looking for that in the edit thing but couldn't find it.

So

We have:

Solution: 
Templates-->Sport-->Sport.doc
OpenDoc.aspx
openDoc.aspx.cs(that is the code-behind of the OpenDoc file)

OpenDoc contains one Button that uses the method btnCreateWordBulletin on click

that method tries to make the path for opening a .doc

and that methods calls the method that will open the doc and activate it.

I hope I explained the structure more.

Comment: So hold on OpenDoc.aspx (and OpenDoc.aspx.cs) are in the same folder as Sport.doc? If so then you would only need `/Sport.doc`. In your example above `../Sport.doc` would be searching for Sport.doc in the Templates folder and not the Sport folder.

Comment: Ow sorry that went wrong while posting.
1.Solution
1.1Templates
1.1.1Sport
1.1.1.1Sport.doc
1. opendoc.aspx and opdendox.aspx.cs

Comment: The solution is found in the comment of Dennis R.

Comment: what you explained only works for documents on the client side